# How do you find out what Effort Values a Pokémon currently has

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Googling "EV calculator" I see redirects to IV calculators (Which I'm not looking for), and this is understood as you really can't tell the effort values of a pokemon from their stats. So how do you figure out how many EVs a pokemon has currently gained?

I'm aware that in the Super Training interface, you can see a sort of diagram of what EVs have been trained, but I'm looking for exact figures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its actually pretty easy to check exact EVs:

- Save your game,
- Use a reset punching bag with the Pokemon you want to check.
- When the bag is used, write down the numbers that appear on the stat graph (they will be negatives, as the reset bag just took the EVs off)
- Reset the game (L + R + Select)

When you reset the game, you'll have the Reset Bag you just used back, and the Pokémon will have its EVs back

Comment: Although this sounds like a great method, is there any other way without a reset bag? I don't have one :3

Comment: They're uncommon, but not rare. Just delete all the small/medium bags you have, and sit there punching the default bag. If the list fills up again, remove some and keep going. The longest I've had to wait is about 20 mins. use a team flare bag first if you have one, you seem to get more bags when using that

Comment: Cool, thanks for that. I'll still wait and see if anyone knows of other ways to find the EVs of a pokemon